# How do I use multiple choices field (tag select field) in custom form/model?

Tags: input, flask, task, flask-admin

I'm interesting in how do I get input field working as default flask-admin multi input field:
[image]
What widget/field should I use?

It seems like i need to use Select2TagsField, but how do i fill it with data? It just show me 'No matches found':

```
class CustomModelView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('things_list',)
    form_extra_fields = {
        'things_list': Select2TagsField(
            'Things',
            coerce=int
        ),
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[Example codes](https://gist.github.com/imwilsonxu/1e7343426135b4a34ce78574012a8f62) of `flask` + `wtforms` + `select2`. Remember to override `SelectMultipleField` to prevent "not a valid choice" error.

Comment: many thanks for native solution (without flask-admin's Select2TagsField field ), but i'm still interesting in how to get Select2TagsField working. Anyway I've found, that I might use Select2Field (which is inherited from WTForms' SelectField), passed multiple=True to it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!  Although it does not fit the question a bit, i've managed to apply it in my project. Only one remark - we doesn't need to override pre_validate function to `pass` to prevent `not a valid choice` error - just pass coerce=int to field constructor.